# Is it better to use INNER JOIN or EXISTS to find belonging to several in m2m relation?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, many-to-many

Given m2m relation: **items-categories** I have three tables:

- **items**,
- **categories** and
- **items_categories** that hold references to both

I want to find an item belonging to **all given** category sets:

```
Find Item 
belonging to a category in [1,3,6] 
and belonging to a category in [7,8,4] 
and belonging to a category in [12,66,42]
and ...
```

There are two ways I can think of to accomplish this in mySQL.

**OPTION A: INNER JOIN:**

```
SELECT id from items 
INNER JOIN category c1 ON (item.id = c1.item_id)
INNER JOIN category c2 ON (item.id = c2.item_id)
INNER JOIN category c3 ON (item.id = c3.item_id)
...
WHERE
c1.category_id IN [1,3,6] AND
c2.category_id IN [7,8,4] AND
c3.category_id IN [12,66,42] AND
...;
```

**OPTION B: EXISTS:**

```
SELECT id from items
WHERE
EXISTS(SELECT category_id FROM category WHERE category.item_id = id AND category_id in [1,3,6] AND
EXISTS(SELECT category_id FROM category WHERE category.item_id = id AND category_id in [7,8,4] AND
EXISTS(SELECT category_id FROM category WHERE category.item_id = id AND category_id in [12,66,42] AND
...;
```

Both options work. The question is: **Which is the fastest / most optimal for large item table?** Or is there an OPTION C I am missing?

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan of each query.

Comment: Option A and Option B might not produce the same result.

Comment: Great stuff, guys! Thank you all for your help and comments ^^

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**OPTION A**

`JOIN` has an advantage over `EXIST` , because it will more efficiently use the indices, especially in case of large tables

Answer (score 16):

A `JOIN` is more efficient, generally speaking.

However, one thing to be aware of is that joins can produce duplicate rows in your output.  For example, if item id was in category 1 and 3, the first `JOIN` would result in two rows for  id 123.  If item id 999 was in categories 1,3,7,8,12, and 66, you would get *eight* rows for 999 in your results (2*2*2).

Duplicate rows are something you need to be aware of and handle.  In this case, you could just use `select distinct id...`.  Eliminating duplicates can get more complicated with a complex query, though.

Comment: Thanks! In the original query I am using distinct. Will distinct make a big difference performance-wise if I am dealing with 100.000+ items?

Comment: @RomanSemko, distinct will affect performance, but it probably won't make a huge difference.

Comment: i'm in the process of converting `exists` with inner joins.  i need to eliminate duplicate results now so i've tried using distinct or group by.  the performance difference is much worse in my case

Answer (score 3):

You are using Join in **Option A** and [subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subquery#Subqueries) in **Option B**. The difference is:

In most cases JOINs are faster than sub-queries and it is very rare for a sub-query to be faster.

In JOINs RDBMS can create an execution plan that is better for your query and can predict what data should be loaded to be processed and save time, unlike the sub-query where it will run all the queries and load all their data to do the processing.

The good thing in sub-queries is that they are more readable than JOINs: that's why most new SQL people prefer them; it is the easy way; but when it comes to performance, JOINS are better in most cases even though they are not hard to read too.

Comment: Most modern optimizers (MySQL's is not) will generate the same execution plan for an equivalent sub-query solution compared to the JOIN. But a JOIN is not necessarily equivalent to a sub-query solution (as dan1111 pointed out)

Answer (score 3):

```
 select distinct `user_posts_id` from `user_posts_boxes`
     where `user_id` = 5 
     and 
     exists (select * from `box` where `user_posts_boxes`.`box_id` = `box`.`id` 
     and `status` in ("A","F"))
     order by `user_posts_id` desc limit 200;



 select distinct `user_posts_id` from `user_posts_boxes`
 INNER JOIN box on box.id = `user_posts_boxes`.`box_id` and box.`status` in ("A","F")
 and box.user_id = 5
 order by `user_posts_id` desc limit 200
```

I tried with both query, But above query works faster for me.Both tables having large dataset. Almost "user_posts_boxes" has 4 million and boxes are 1.5 million.

First query took = 0.147 ms
2nd Query almost = 0.5 to 0.9 MS

But my database tables are inno db and having physical relationships are also applied.

SO I should go for exists  but it also depends upon how you have your db structure.

Answer (score 1):

Also, read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/semijoins.html) from Mysql docs which talks about this and **new changes** in the previous versions and how MySql actually executes `exists`.

> If a subquery meets the preceding criteria, MySQL converts it to a semijoin (or, in MySQL 8.0.17 or later, an antijoin if applicable) and makes a cost-based choice from these strategies:
>
> Convert the subquery to a join, or use table pullout and run the query
> as an inner join between subquery tables and outer tables. Table
> pullout pulls a table out from the subquery to the outer query.
>
> ...